# `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError` inside a jar which I build while running in Android 4.4.*

Tags: java, android, android-4.4-kitkat

I have a jar built using `maven`. The project from which the jar was build has no native dependencies. It runs fine in all devices except few devices having android `4.4.2` and `4.4.4`. Can someone help me with this, right now my option is to disable the feature for all devices below `5.0`

**Edit 1:**

Debugging further I found that the `LazyHolder` implementation of my singleton class is failing as in runtime the constructor is unable to resolve the static class.

```
Caused by java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: <muted>
       at com.a.b.controller.Controller.getInstance + 31(Controller.java:31)
       at com.a.b.controller.Controller.k + 184(Controller.java:184)
       at com.a.b.core.parser.f.m + 53(ff.java:53)
       at com.a.b.core.parser.f.n + 67(f.java:67)
       at a.b.c.d.e$classify$$inlined$use$lambda$1.invokeSuspend(e.java:90)
       at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith + 32(BaseContinuationImpl.java:32)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run + 233(DispatchedTask.java:233)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely + 594(CoroutineScheduler.java:594)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.access$getSchedulerName$p + 60(CoroutineScheduler.java:60)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run + 742(CoroutineScheduler.java:742)
```

**Edit 2:**

I created a fix by passing in the android version into my jar and then not using `LazyHolder` for versions less than `4.4.*` or lesser. Feel free to suggest better solutions.

Comment: Please feel free to ask if you need any additional information

Comment: Please share the complete error and stacktrace

Comment: I have added the stack-trace, also I had to obfuscate it for obvious reasons

Comment: Looks like something in the Controller interface is accessing Android libraries which don't exist or have been modified since 4.4.*. When you run a get instance, it tries to load the class of the controller which fails because of some dependency. Have a look at the imports and other static fields in the controller.

Comment: Yes, its trying to access the `LazyHolder` class  to get the instance. What happens is in `4.4.*` the dex created somehow skips this class. I read this up somewhere and changes my implementation to not have `LazyHolders` in 4.4.* or less

FYI.. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom

Comment: When you say LazyHolder, do you mean the exact same implementation ? In that case you need to look at the implementation of the enclosed class (in the example the class name is Something).
Even if you don't directly access native API's, it is very probably that some of the libraries you use internally reference some native API which does not exist in 4.4.*

Comment: My java project has only one external dependency with is `org.json`. I believe it doesnt have any native dependencies.

Comment: Try creating a sample project with org.json on android 4.4.x and verify if that works. If it doesnt, then the problem is with org.json, else you should be looking somewhere else

Comment: Further research found that the issue is related to `dex` creation in android 4.4.* as it tries to create a single `dex` file (as mutildex was not available in this build) and removes some classes and function.

Comment: How did you resolve it ?

Comment: I could never resolve it. I wrote a piece of code to check whether its 4.4.* or less and avoided lazy loading in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have waited for a while now to get an appropriate answer to this question. Unfortunately, this is not easy to reproduce and might be a corner scenario as most android developers are not concerned about version 4 or less. So I have decided to put all my findings as an answer to this question.

In my scenario, I had LazyHolder(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom) implementation for initializing my central object. But the problem was when ran on Android 4.4.* devices the lazy-holder failed to get the static class. The class was not available at runtime. I ran the app in debug mode on an android 4.4.2 device and was able to clearly pinpoint this.

Reading further, I found that the static class is probably getting into another dex file while my constructor in one altogether a different one(this is pretty common when multiDex was enabled in 4.4.* it seems).

Finally, the hack was to initialize normally in case of android version less than 5 and with lazy-holder if it's above 5